# how to use drupal 7 module from non drupal php website

Tags: 7

I wanted to use drupal 7 five star rating in my non drupal php website. How can i implement it.

I have installed the drupal 7 in my website root and I have added the five star rating module it works fine, If I navigate to localhost/mysite/drupal/ but I want those five star rating functionality to be implemented in my index.php file which is in localhost/mysite/index.php.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest perhaps way to do it is to create a custom module, that calls and returns the rating widget, and display it either in a iFrame, or via REST service. I would probably go with the REST. You will also need to move css and images for styling the REST code from the Fivestar module.